# Show local image by JavaScript (mobile camera)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my code for showing a image from user local machine, but it sometimes doesn't work for the first time. Specially when (on mobile) user take a picture from camera.

It almost always doesn't work for the first time that user select his image.

I use `Image()` to get the width and height of image for `aspectRatio` of `resizable`.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload Image</title>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .select-img {
            width: 450px;
            height: 250px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 3px dashed gray;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        #image {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="select-img">
        <p>Select Image</p>
    </div>

    <img id="image">

    <script>
        function upload (file) {
            var fr = new FileReader();

            fr.onload = function (event) {
                var src = event.target.result;
                var img = new Image();

                img.onload = function () {
                    $('.select-img').remove();
                    $('#image').css('display', 'block').attr('src', src).resizable({ aspectRatio: this.width / this.height });
                };

               img.src = src;
            };

            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        $('.select-img').click(function () {
            var fileInput = $(document.createElement("input"));
            fileInput.attr('type', 'file');
            fileInput.attr('accept', 'image/*');
            fileInput.trigger('click');

            $(fileInput).on('change', function (ev) {
                upload(ev.target.files[0]);
            });

            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any alerts in console? Which browsers are you testing with on Mobile?

Comment: @Twisty There is not alert in console. I'm using Chrome, but any other browser doesn't work!

Comment: Initial testing, plus found some code that needed some optimization: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/188x0w0u/ - for mobile testing, use: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/188x0w0u/show/

Answer (score 0):

Did some intitial testing via FireFox on desktop and Chrome on Android. Both work properly to display the image:

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/188x0w0u - for mobile testing, use: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/188x0w0u/show

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function upload(file) {
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function(event) {
      var src = event.target.result;
      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = function() {
        $('.select-img').remove();
        $('#image').css('display', 'block').attr('src', src).resizable({
          aspectRatio: this.width / this.height
        });
      };
      img.src = src;
    };

    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  $('.select-img').click(function() {
    var fileInput = $("<input>", {
      type: "file",
      accept: "image/*"
    });
    fileInput.trigger('click');

    fileInput.on('change', function(ev) {
      upload(ev.target.files[0]);
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Minor switches to code to make better use of jQuery. this worked in both capturing a photo from camera and selecting photo from documents on the mobile device.

Resizing fails, and for me this was expected. Add Touch punch:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

New Test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/188x0w0u/2/

Mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/188x0w0u/2/show/

Now the `.resizable()` works on mobile too.

Comment: It doesn't work on mobile when I take a picture from front camera (selfie)!!

Comment: @M.Mohammadi I was unable to replicate the issue. Please describe the exacte details to replicate the issue, include phone and browser you are using for testing.

Comment: I am using Galaxy S8+ and Chrome 62.0.3202.84; but my clients (all of them) has the same problem! It just happens by using front camera.

Comment: I tested using Samsung Galaxy S8+ with Chrome and the front facing camera without issue. Please describe how I can replicate the issue.